# How to use concept of virtualisation to render large json in innerHtml of pre tag in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am rendering json in pre tag through innerhtml in an angular application, Now it works perfectly fine but the render becomes slow and scrolling is also very slow when the json is huge. Is there a way to use concept of virtualisation and render only what is visible at a particular time? I know there's a module called ScrollingModule to do so but I am confused how to do it for innerHtml of a pre tag.

My html ->

```
           <pre
            [innerHTML]="syntaxHighlight()"
            class="pre-code"
            ></pre>
```

Where in syntaxHighlight function I am basically doing some editing of json to prettify it, which is ->

```
syntaxHighlight() {
        let json = JSON.stringify(this.jsonToBeRendered, undefined, 2);
        // let json = this.jsonToBeRendered;
        json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match: any) {
            let cls = 'number';
            if (/^"/.test(match)) {
                if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                    cls = 'key';
                } else {
                    cls = 'string';
                }
            } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'boolean';
            } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'null';
            }
            return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
        });
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thankss :)